# WordML bold font on right-to-left language

Tags: wordml

Need your help with formatting text as bold + right-to-left.
For now I succeed to get only one of the two, but not both in the same time.

I've tried this:

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="D12"/>
    <w:bidi/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rtl/>
      <w:bold w:lang w:bidi="HE"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>טקסט</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`<w:b-cs/>`** rather then `<w:bold w:lang w:bidi="HE"/>`

For more tags you can create a document in word that contain the style that you need, save it on word2003 (xml format) and open it with notepad and see which tag Microsoft Word used.